# Problems with the ADT List Iterator in C

Tags: c, list, iterator, malloc, abstract-data-type

i'm making the `ADT List Iterator` in `C`.
When I use the primitive to print the list to the beginning they work correctly. But then, inside the main, I want to create the iterator over the list and look if the delete primitive works(i't works correctly) but then I want to print the list again with `print_list_iterator()` again, it doesn't works. 
 I have my structs like this:

```
typedef struct node{
    struct node *next;
    void *data;
}nodo_t;

typedef struct list{
    struct node *head;
}list_t;

typedef struct iterator{
    node_t **pn;
}list_iterator_t;
```

These are the primitives of the `ADT Iterator` that i am working with;

```
list_iterator_t * list_iterator_create(list_t * l){
    struct iterator *li = malloc(sizeof(struct iterator));
    if(li == NULL)
        return NULL;
    li->pn = &(l->head);
    return li;
}

bool list_iterator_next(list_iterator_t *li){
    if(*li->pn == NULL){
        return false;
    }
    *li->pn = (*li->pn)->next;
    return true;
}
void *list_iterator_current(const list_iterator_t *li){
    if((*li->pn) == NULL){
        return NULL;
    }
    return (*li->pn)->data;
}
```

Here my primitive to delete de iterator;

```
void *list_iterator_delete(lista_iterator_t *li){

    if(*li->pn == NULL)
        return NULL;

    struct node *aux;
    void *aux_data = (*li->pn)->data;

    aux = (*li->pn);
    *li->pn = (*li->pn)->next;

    free(aux);
    return aux_data;
}
```

Then, if i want to print the list i'm using:

```
void print_list_iterator(lista_t * l){

    for(list_iterator_t *li =list_iterator_create(l);
        !list_iterator_finish(li);
        list_iterator_next(li)
        ){
        int *e = list_iterator_current(li);
        printf("%d -> ",*e);
    }
}
```

If I use the `print_list_iterator()`, then in the main it doesn't let me create an iterator on the same list, and use my primitives.
Any ideas?
By the way, I would like to know if these primitives are well implemented.

Function test in the main:
int main(){

```
  list_t *dest = list_create();
    list_iterator_t *iter = list_iterator_create(dest);
    int vector[] = {88,99,1,0,5,106,22,44,56,3,5,6,3,4,6};
        size_t vector_size = sizeof(vector)/sizeof(vector[0]);
        for(size_t i=0; i<vector_size; i++)
            list_append(dest, vector +i);
        list_iterator_delete(iter);
        list_iterator_delete(iter);
        list_iterator_delete(iter);
        list_iterator_delete(iter);
        print_list_iterator(dest);
```

In terminal:

```
   MacBook-Air: UltraT$ gcc iterator_double_pointers.c -std=c99 -Wall -pedantic -o it2
    MacBook-Air: UltraT$ ./it2
    5 -> 106 -> 22 -> 44 -> 56 -> 3 -> 5 -> 6 -> 3 -> 4 -> 6 ->
```

So, my function are working right, but:
If I call the print function (which is actually a function that runs through the list with the iterator primitives, that's why I shared the iterator primitives since there may be some error there)

```
    print_list_iterator(destino);
    list_iterator_delete(iter);
    print_list_iterator(destino);
    list_iterator_delete(iter);
    list_iterator_delete(iter);
    list_iterator_delete(iter);
```

The result in terminal:

```
MacBook-Air:tp2 UltraT$ ./it2
88 -> 99 -> 1 -> 0 -> 5 -> 106 -> 22 -> 44 -> 56 -> 3 -> 5 -> 6 -> 3 -> 4 -> 6 ->
```

It does not work.

That is why my function of eliminating sometimes works and sometimes not. I don't know where the problem is if in the print function (which actually goes through the list) or in the delete function

Comment: Please read the help about providing a minimum complete verifiable example with your question.  It will increase the chance you'll get the help you want.

Comment: What Gene is referring to is this [mcve].

Comment: There was a question about this just yesterday, please use a search. You need a pointer to the pointer of the prev element in the iterator!

Comment: @AnttiHaapala  Yes, you are right about the post. But here I am not asking the same thing, here the function I did works correctly( list_iterator_delete() ) if I create an iterator on the list in the main. Then if I call the function print_list_iterator() I can print on the screen, but after using this function (which creates me another iterator on the list that I ask you to print) I can't use the iterator in previously created.

Comment: @Gene Yes, you are right, I will try to summarize my problem. I thought it was good to show all the information I have, because my problem can be in any of the primitives.
If I only shared the print_list_iterator() and list_iterator_delete() function, perhaps there was little information to analyze the problem.

Comment: It is the same problem, you need to relink the list over the deleted node

Comment: @AnttiHaapala sorry , but i am not understanding you. If you can, look at the edition I made to the post. My delete function works (sometimes). I don't know if the problem is eliminating or going through the list (print)

Comment: @Renzo: in your delete function, after you've deleted the current node, the prior node will still point to the now deleted node, or if it was the first one, head will still point to it.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError can you help me with the code?

Comment: Take a look at [this example](https://gist.github.com/icheishvili/4190607) for inspiration (not mine).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved it by using *prev and *curr(current node).
In the future I want to change the function to use it with double pointers.

```
struct list_iterator{

    node_t *prev;
    node_t *curr;
    list_t *l_iter;
};

typedef struct list_iterator list_iterator_t

void * delete_iterator_list(list_iterator_t * li) {

    if (list_iterator_finish (li))
        return NULL;

    struct node * aux_node;
    void * data;

    if (! li-> prev) {
        data = li-> curr-> data;
        aux_node = li-> curr;
        li-> l_iter-> head = aux_node-> next;
        li-> curr = li-> l_iter-> head;
    }
    else if (li-> curr-> next == NULL) {
        data = li-> curr-> data;
        aux_node = li-> curr;
        li-> curr = li-> curr-> next;
        li-> prev-> next = li-> curr;
    }
    else {
        data = li-> curr-> data;
        aux_node = li-> curr;
        li-> curr = li-> curr-> next;
        li-> prev-> next = li-> curr;
    }
    free (aux_node);
    return data;
```